# configuring nginx and tomcat together

Tags: nginx, web-server, tomcat, java

I am trying to figure out exactly how to configure nginx and tomcat to work together correctly.

Nginx has a `worker connections` setting and tomcat has `max threads` (assuming native apr connector for tomcat). Since nginx is connecting with HTTP/1.0 to backend, keepalive is not needed for tomcat.

I set `keep-alive timeout` to 30s in nginx. If 100 req/s is the target and each request finishes in 1s, there can be 100 requests * 30 seconds each = 3000 concurrent connections that can be opened to nginx and there will be 100 concurrent connections to tomcat.

So if I set `worker connections` to 6000 in nginx (worker process is 1, and nginx consumes 2 connection per request I think. One for client and one for backend) and `max threads` to 100 in tomcat (which is already 200 by default), this will work.

Is there any conceptual problem in this calculation? The exact numbers do not matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two points you should consider in working out the above calculations:

- There is a difference between a connection and a thread. This [page](http://tomcat-configure.blogspot.com/2009/01/tomcat-maxthreads-configuration.html) breaks this down a bit, but each request is a thread. There will be many requests per connection.
- RAM is another monitoring factor here. How much memory does each thread take up and how much do you have on your machine can be limiting factors.

Otherwise it looks pretty sound.

Answer (score -1):

While forwarding requests from nginx to tomcat:
please remember:

you need to set protocol http/1.1 & set connection to "" to enable connection persistence

regards
vj

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).